# Setting Apache to be visible on the Internet

Tags: apache-2.2

could you help me with Apache2 configuration (on Ubuntu 10.04) to be visible on my public IP address? I'd like to know what to set and in which configuration files.

thank you

Comment: Is there some way to trougleshoot this problem?

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf there is a line

ServerName localhost
Should I change it to my public IP?

Comment: not completly related, but once it will be available on a public address you should read and modify settings in the file: /etc/apache2/conf.d/security as some parameters should be switched off for public webserver security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this machine is directly connected to the internet, no further configuration should be needed.
If there is a router in between you and the internet, forward TCP ports 80 and 443 to the web server.

Comment: ifconfig shows 
eth0
inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
So I'm forwarding in the router port 80 and 443 to 192.168.1.101

Comment: Is there some way to trougleshoot this problem?

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf there is a line

ServerName localhost
Should I change it to my public IP?

Comment: You can check to see if its listening on port 80, and what IPs its listening on via netstat -an. Given that eth0 shows 192.168.1.101, the router should be configured correctly. You can also try visiting http://192.168.1.101/ and see if a page loads ( If you are on behind the router, easiest if you are on the same subnet as the server aka 192.168.1.xxx )